# What do two commas mean?

Tags: r, syntax

First I have a slightly embarrassing question. What do the commas in R represent? 
For example, whenever there's code that's like `unique[x3,]` or something similar, What is the comma doing before the bracket?

Second,

```
mosaicplot(UCBAdmissions[,,i],)
```

what do the two commas inside the square bracket mean?

Comment: I spent a while searching and this question is difficult to google. Hopefully the indexer can pick up my comment. I was searching for "square bracket comma".

Answer (score 11):

The best way to understand these things is to try them out on your own and see what they do!

In general:

```
mydf[1, ] ## Get the first row
mydf[, 3] ## Get the third column
```

The UCBAdmissions has more than two dimensions, so

```
UCBAdmissions[, , 1] ## Get the first table in the 3D array
```

Of course, these can be combined. The UCBAdmissions sample data is a set of 6 two-by-two table:

```
dim(UCBAdmissions)
# [1] 2 2 6
```

Let's imagine you wanted the first row from just the first two tables:

```
UCBAdmissions[1, , c(1, 2)]
#         Dept
# Gender     A   B
#   Male   512 353
#   Female  89  17
```